# Android SDK is Unavailable in the First Startup of Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I've been trying to install Android Studio for learning flutter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUo6W.png) As I try to install Android Studio, and run it for the first time, I arrive at the following screen

Comment: what's the output of `flutter doctor -v` command?

Answer (score 0):

use vpn app , looks like your region is denied